# bindfs works, but not via /etc/fstab

Tags: linux, mount, fuse

I can do a bind mount like this:

```
bindfs -u target --mirror=target /home/source/import/target /home/target
umount /home/target
```

But it fails, if I try to do the same thing via `/etc/fstab`:

```
# fstab line:
/home/source/import/target /home/target  fuse.bindfs  mirror=target 0    0
```

Try to mount via `/etc/fstab`:

```
LANG=C mount /home/target

mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /home/source/import/target,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
```

But `dmesg` does not contain a new entry.

`target` and `source` are the name of directories and the name of two linux users.

What is wrong?

Hints how to debug this are welcome.

Alternative solutions are welcome, too. All I want is that new files created by user `target` in `/home/target` are visible for user `source` in `/home/source/import/target`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the deprecated syntax for fstab entries as found in [`man bindfs`](https://bindfs.org/docs/bindfs.1.html#sect14)?

```
# fstab line:
bindfs#/home/source/import/target /home/target  fuse  mirror=target 0    0
```

Comment: I tried your line, but it was the same. I found the answer: The RPM fuse was missing.

Answer (score 0):

One day later I found the solution myself.

The RPM `fuse` package was not installed. Mounting via `/etc/fstab` seems to need it.

Mounting on the command line seems to not need it.

Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me all the time. Replaces symlinking i used to do in the past:

```
/mnt/data/xyzuser/VirtualBoxVMs  /home/xyzuser/VirtualBox\040VMs  none    defaults,bind,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=5,x-gvfs-hide     0 0
```